# DNS Issues from domain dns health report

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm hoping somebody can help here as I'm totally lost!

My domain **darksideiptv.com** is showing errors, when I try and link a piece of software to my control panel it is hit and miss whether or not it will receive a response, and update from the server? I believe it is looking in 2 different places for the info, sometimes it gets it right other times it doesnt?

Below is the report on my domain from **intoDNS**:

Any advice on how to rectify would be greatly appreciated.

My domain is registered with **Godaddy**, but my server and the domain are with **OVH**.

> Delegation
>
> Superfluous name server listed at parent: pdns07.domaincontrol.com
>
> A name server listed at the parent, but not at the child, was found.
>   This is most likely an administrative error. You should update the
>   parent to match the name servers at the child as soon as possible.
>
> Superfluous name server listed at parent: pdns08.domaincontrol.com
>
> A name server listed at the parent, but not at the child, was found.
>   This is most likely an administrative error. You should update the
>   parent to match the name servers at the child as soon as possible.
>
> Total parent/child glue mismatch.
>
> The parent lists name servers that the child doesnt know about, see
>   details in advanced. This configuration could actually work but breaks
>   very easily if one of these zones change slightly. Nameserver
>   dns11.ovh.net.
>
> Everything is fine.
>
> All tests successful in this part, no errors or warnings.
>   ns11.ovh.net.
>
> Everything is fine.
>
> All tests successful in this part, no errors or warnings. Consistency
>
> 2 different serials found.
>
> The SOA serial is not the same on all name servers. This is usually
>   due to misconfiguration, but can sometimes be the result of slow zone
>   propagation to secondary name servers.
>
> 2 different SOA records found.
>
> The SOA record are not the same among all name servers. This is
>   usually due to misconfiguration. SOA
>
> Delivery over IPv4 to tech@ovh.net could not be done.
>
> Failed to deliver email for SOA RNAME of darksideiptv.com
>   (tech.ovh.net) using tech@ovh.net.
>
> DNSCheck failed to deliver email to the email address listed as the
>   one responsible for the zone. Connectivity
>
> Everything is fine.
>
> All tests successful in this part, no errors or warnings. DNSSEC
>
> Everything is fine.
>
> All tests successful in this part, no errors or warnings.

Hope somebody can advise as I'm completely baffled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name servers listed in the domain registration still point to GoDaddy name servers. Update the domain registration information to point to the OVH name servers.

Currently the root .com name servers say the name servers for your domain are GoDaddy - this information comes from what is entered in the domain registration. The name server records at GoDaddy say the name servers for your domain are OVH - these come from the NS records listed in a DNS control panel. They should both be saying the same thing.

`dig +trace darkspideiptv.com` shows in part:

```
darksideiptv.com.       172800  IN      NS      pdns07.domaincontrol.com.
darksideiptv.com.       172800  IN      NS      pdns08.domaincontrol.com.
;; Received 122 bytes from 192.35.51.30#53(192.35.51.30) in 79 ms

darksideiptv.com.       3600    IN      A       151.80.104.45
darksideiptv.com.       3600    IN      NS      dns11.ovh.net.
darksideiptv.com.       3600    IN      NS      ns11.ovh.net.
;; Received 96 bytes from 216.69.185.53#53(216.69.185.53) in 13 ms
```

`whois darksideiptv.com` shows in part:

```
Name Server: PDNS07.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
Name Server: PDNS08.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
```

Comment: Ok Thats great thank you, that makes a whole lot more sense than what i was previously reading in the report

Comment: Stiil confused though? both my server and godaddy already have the ovh nameservers listed?